# ¿Qué función utilizar para insertar un carácter en una cadena?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Tengo el siguiente campo en mi tabla `142-5245548`, ¿hay alguna función que me permita insertar un `-` en la mitad de la cadena? El resultado esperado sería: `142-524-5548`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma habitual sería usando [`SUBSTR()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions162.htm) para recortar las dos "mitades" y agregar un guión en el medio. Esta función espera:  una cadena, una posición inicial y la longitud de recorte. La posición inicial puede ser negativa, lo cual se interpreta contando de atrás hacia adelante. En este ejemplo:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(ID,1,7) || '-' || SUBSTR(ID,-4)
       FROM (SELECT '142-5245548' "ID" FROM DUAL);
```

Recortamos los primeros 7 caracteres `SUBSTR(ID,1,7)` y lo últimos 4 `SUBSTR(ID,-4)`, en el medio agregamos el guión.

Otra forma interesante pero más compleja, podría ser usando expresiones regulares, tal como proponen en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18231810/6836377), usando el patrón `^(.{7})` quecuenta los primeros 7 caracteres para luego insertar el guión.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(ID, '^(.{7})', '\1-') as res
       FROM (SELECT '142-5245548' "ID" FROM DUAL);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, duda despejada